# When is ARCore going to version 1.0?

Tags: arcore

When will ARCore become the Version 1.0 from the preview version, when will it be around? Please tell me if there is information somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It came to Version 1.0.0 on February 23, 2018. More information:

https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/

and

https://www.blog.google/products/google-vr/announcing-arcore-10-and-new-updates-google-lens/